# Union of some open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $B_n$ denote the open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of radius $n$ centered at $(n,0)$.

$$A=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n$$

Show that $A$ is the open right half plane. i.e. $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x>0\}$.

So here is what I do. Suppose that $(u,v) \in A$. Then $(u,v)$ satisfy $(u-n)^2+v^2<n^2$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Draw pictures it will follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little error in your last inequality: You should show $\sqrt{(u-n)^2+v^2}<n$, or: $(u-n)^2+v^2<n^2$. Since the quadrartic terms cancel, all works out nicely, check it!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $A=\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} B_n$, then $A\subset \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x>0\}$ is obvious , Now you should show that for each point $(x,y)$ with $x>0$ in the right half plane, it must lies in a circle big enough. Then $A\supset \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x>0\}$. So the answer follows.